# Can't figure out the right datetime format when connecting to an API

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to connect to an API but was having trouble figure out the right datetime format. The document says it follows this format: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.000Z

Example: "2019-03-07T10:30:00-0400"

I can only get it working if use `datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()`

But if I want to try a specific time like this `datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 12, 0, 0).isoformat()`, it'd give me 500 error: 'message': 'Internal server error', 'type': 'INTEGRATION_FAILURE', 'statusCode': '500'.

What datetime format should I use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.strftime`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 12, 0, 0).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")) #or "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"
#--> 2019-08-18T12:00:00.000000Z
```